# Difficulty getting more than exact field match results on sunspot/solr with qf= and defType=edismax parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot

we are PublicLab.org appreciate Sunspot and are in the process of deploying it to production.

Our testing and development was done with the embedded Solr engine found in sunspot_solr (2.2.6) gem.

Now for production we are using a Solr 5.3 container (as found in https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/). In this case, the default Sunspot query is [not working well in the Solr service](https://github.com/publiclab/plots2/pull/1466#issuecomment-308880170), specifically, either the parameters `qf=title_text+body_text+comment_text` OR `defType=edismax` (both of which are defaults as generated by Sunspot in our Rails app's `Node.search` query) cause Solr to return only some results and not others. It seems that it only returns an exact, case-sensitive match of the title field. For example:

- https://publiclab.org/searches/test/test?q=Moderation
- https://publiclab.org/searches/test/test?q=moderation

But adjusting these parameters for production -- as detailed [in this pull request](https://github.com/publiclab/plots2/pull/1466), while it returns full results in the production environment (containerized Solr), causes results to break in development (the embedded Solr engine from the `sunspot` gem).

So, either we need to

a) figure out why the seemingly well-formed sunspot-generated query only matches exact title text and change that, OR

b) figure out why our manual edits to the query return nothing at all in embedded (sunspot gem) Solr

We've also posted on the sunspot issue tracker: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/863

Thanks for any possible help!

Comment: Either your indexed field does not have a lower case filter or your field does not have a lowercase query analyser.

Comment: Our indexed field is pretty simple, vanilla `sunspot`: https://github.com/publiclab/plots2/blob/master/app/models/node.rb#L25 --
 just `text "title"` -- isn't it supposed to be case insensitive by default?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ex configurations for the field text_general in your solr schema.xml: 

  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Here word "Moderation" is indexed as "moderation" and all query are converted to lower case. Also you may want to check your solr default qf & df params.

1.Also it would be helpful if can share your schema and solrconfig files.

2.Run the query from solr ui with debug=on which will give a complete trace of how the query is being parsed and how result is matched.

Comment: Here are our schema files, but this is after we decided to switch to a containerized and not embedded Solr -- but just in case it's helpful:  https://github.com/publiclab/plots2/tree/cf22ee7f002be15e8cf630e15da7687ff5a59a57/config/solr

Answer (score 0):

Our (non-) solution: we've ended up switching away from the embedded Solr provided in the `sunspot_solr` gem on Rails, and using a containerized (and more up-to-date) Solr. This has bypassed the issue.